# What does "take away from" mean?

Tags: verbs, phrase-meaning

I am reading a book which contains a sentence that reads:

> Something Dave took away from his time at IDEO was the importance of embodying your ideas in a physical prototype.

What does it mean to "take away from" one's time?

Answer (score 2):

It means to learn from. It treats the knowledge/experience/lessons that Dave gained as a physical object that Dave "took away from" the place where it was gained.

> Something Dave took away from his time at IDEO was the importance of embodying your ideas in a physical prototype.

Has a similar meaning to

> Something Dave learned from his time at IDEO was the importance of embodying your ideas in a physical prototype.

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-away):

> **take sth away**
>
> ...
>
> **to get a particular message or piece of information from something you read or are told :**
>
> What I took away from his talk is that going to university is definitely worth it.